# How can I take out items from a container?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a few bins with finished goods like toys, rings, scepters and the like inside, but they also have items that I don't want to sell (crutches, rope, soap, splints, etc). Currently they're in a stockpile in which I disabled those types of finished good, but no dwarf takes them out of there.

It makes trading a bit more annoying , because I can't trade the whole bin. So, how can I take them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dwarf will only take an item out of a stockpile if there's a reason for it; being in an incorrect stockpile isn't reason enough on its own.

However, dwarves will take an item out of an incorrect stockpile in order to place it into a different, valid stockpile (as long as there's space in the new stockpile).

The only time a dwarf will take an item out of a *valid* stockpile to place it in a different stockpile is if one of the two stockpiles is set to give to/take from the other.

So, to get the items out of the containers in the first stockpile, make sure there's space in another stockpile (and enough spare bins if you want them put in the bin) for that kind of item. If that alone isn't working, link the stockpiles in the desired direction.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I did set up a different stickpile with those types enabled, or at least I thought about doing it. Will check.

Comment: I might be totally wrong as well! If it turns out I am I'll update it :D Dumping is a tedious way to do it manually

Comment: Eventually they moved the items... lazy creatures!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest you can do without much *future* hassle is to manage your stockpiles in a more fine-grained manner - set one or more finished goods stockpiles to accept only the crafts you want to be in the bins (rings, scepters, toys, whichever you need). But don't forget to also set up stockpiles to accept the rest of the finished goods, sans the desired crafts.

And I think you are aware, but trading the whole bin also trades the bin itself, so if you're short on wood and metal, it might not be the best idea.

Comment: Yeah, I was starting to learn doing that kind of micromanagement and I noticed this issue.